# check the neighbours of a cell in a vector Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors

```
K=[1 1 1 2 1 2 1 4 2 10 4 5 1]
```

and

```
L=[2 0 1 2 1 2 1 3 2 0 1 2 1]
```

I want to compare the value of the 7th element in each vector with the neighbours of this value, where the neighbours are 5 elements next to this element in each side. So for `K`, the 7th element is `1` and the neighbours are `1 1 1 2 1 2` (left neighbours) and `4 2 10 4 5 1` (right neighbours).

For `L`, the 7th element is `1` and the neighbours are `2 0 1 2 1 2` (left neighbours) and `3 2 0 1 2 1` (right neighbours). If the difference between the 7th value and each of its neighbours is above a certain threshold then I'll do something e.g X=1, if not then I'll do another thing e.g `X=2`.

So in my example I'll set the threshold to 3, so for K the 7th element value is 1 and the difference between it and two of its neighbours 10,5 are more than the threshold value 3 so X will be 1. For L the 5th element value is 1 and the difference between it and all of its neighbours is less than the threshold value 3 so X will be 2. So I'm wondering if anyone could assist me to do this condition, I'm not sure if this can be done without loops to save time.

Comment: for the 5th element in a vector there are only 4 elements from one side (1 to 4)...

Comment: That's why I tried to edit his post to the 7th element instead of 5th, but editing hasn't been accepted for some reason. It really seems to be the 7th though.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this condition using `any` and `or`:

```
N = 5; % reference index
T = 3; % threshold

V = L; % used to pass the vector L to the if-statement
% V = K;

% formulate if-statement to check for values
% below/above index N and check if any difference
% exceeds the threshold
% the or-statement (because it does not matter if the 
% threshold is exceeded above index N or below)
% is expressed as |

if any((V(1:N-1)-V(N))>T) | any((V(N+1:end)-V(N))>T)
    X = 1;
else
    X = 2;
end
```

*Note*
Depending on your Matlab version `V(1:N-1)-V(N)` will not work, because the matrix dimensions do not agree. In this case use: `V(1:N-1)-ones(size(V(1:N-1))).*V(N)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm just wondering if I want to ignore the result if the difference between the value and its neighbors was above `T` only if the neighbor was not zero. So for example, if `T=3` and `K=[1 1 1 2 1 2 10 4 2 10 0 5 1]` then `X=1` because there are couple of elements with diff. more than `T` inc the 11th element`0`, but if `K=[8 7 8 9 7 7 10 7 7 8 0 9 8]` then `X=1` although the diff. between it and the 11th element is `>T` but this is because the 11th element is zero`0`. Please let me know if any more clarification needed. Thanks in advance

Comment: I was wondering if got the chance to check my previous comment, I've also posted a new question regarding this that can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287703/check-if-the-difference-between-the-neighbors-of-a-cell-in-a-vector-above-a-thre