# Check if the difference between the neighbors of a cell in a vector above a threshold where all the neighbors are non-zeros

Tags: matlab, matrix

`K=[1 1 1 2 1 2 10 4 2 10 0 5 1]` is a vector, I want to compare the value of the 7th element in `K` with the neighbours of this value, where the neighbours are 6 elements next to this element in each side. So for K, the 7th element is 10 and the neighbours are 1 1 1 2 1 2 (left neighbours) and 4 2 10 4 5 1 (right neighbours).If the difference between the 7th value and each of its neighbours is above a certain threshold then I'll do something e.g X=1, if not then I'll do another thing e.g X=2.
So in my example below I set the threshold to 3, so for K the 7th element value is 10 and the difference between it and two of its neighbours 10,5 are more than the threshold value 3 so X will be 1. I'm comparing the X=1 because there are couple of elements with diff. more than T inc the 11th element`0`, but if `K=[8 7 8 9 7 7 10 7 7 8 0 9 8]` then X=2 although the diff. between it and the 11th element is >T but this is because the 11th element is zero`0`.

I'm using the below script related to my other question found here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257161/check-the-neighbours-of-a-cell-in-a-vector-matlab)

```
N = 6; % reference index
T = 3; % threshold

V = K;

% formulate if-statement to check for values
% below/above index N and check if any difference
% exceeds the threshold
% the or-statement (because it does not matter if the 
% threshold is exceeded above index N or below)
% is expressed as |

if any((V(1:N-1)-V(N))>T) | any((V(N+1:end)-V(N))>T)
    X = 1;
else
    X = 2;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I think you should check **diff** in-build function of matlab it solves my problem.